# WP-CLI throwing PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function apply_filters()

Tags: wp-cli

I have a migration script I'm using to copy my production environment to a dev server. Essentially it copies the files, exports/imports the MySQL database (using the `wp db export` and `wp db import` syntax), and then I'm using WP-CLI to deactivate and uninstall wordfence and w3-total-cache so they don't interfere with my development environment. I also have a list of files to remove to completely clean up those plugins. The whole script works great on one of my servers, but on another server I get the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function apply_filters() in /[path]/wp-includes/load.php on line 317`

Both servers are seemingly identical. I'm managing them both with serverpilot.io, both are the same version of Ubuntu on Digital Ocean.

Has anyone seen this before?

P.S. I don't think it's relevant since the same setup is working on another server, but I'm calling the specific PHP version I want and executing the wp-cli.phar with --path defined, like so:

`/opt/sp/php5.6/bin/php /usr/local/bin/wp-cli.phar plugin uninstall --deactivate wordfence w3-total-cache --path="$DEVDIR/public"`

Comment: Have you updated to latest version?

Comment: @Dan9 wow, can't believe I didn't try that! that seems to have fixed it. I am getting warnings still, but it works!

Comment: Have you tried looking up what the contents of `$DEVDIR` are? Like: `echo "${DEVDIR}"` – also note the quotes in case you got spaces in there?